# I cannot give the user a reward for the video reward

Tags: admob, ads

Create a stories app I want the user to see the ad in the first chapter to follow the rest of the story.

Note that I am using activity in all chapters of the story through webview1 displayed on the HTML page for the first chapter, then webview2, displays the HTML page for the second chapter, and I want a button between them that displays the ad and opens webview2

webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/11.html"); webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

If he saw an ad, he will reward the following

webView1=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);  webView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/11.html"); webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: Do you want to create an android app? why you used HTML tag?

Comment: follow this guide https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads

Comment: Really android studio and use web viewer to view written html stories

Comment: I don't know where to place the condition (see the ad and then Web Viewer2)

Answer (score 0):

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mrewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                mrewardedVideoAd.show();

            }else
                { AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("***alarm***");


                alertDialog.setMessage("....no ad load... ");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
                    mrewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                            new AdRequest.Builder().build());

                }
        }
    });


 @Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    webView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```